# How is an index used in an query with aggregation?

Tags: sql, indexing, group-by, aggregate-functions

Given a query like

```
SELECT franchise, MAX(worth)
FROM figurines
GROUP BY franchise
```

what sort of index would speed this query up, and how would the database use that index?

If more detail is required, assume that the column `franchise` has a relatively low cardinality and that `worth` has a very high cardinality.

I personally am using mysql, but I'm looking for a general understanding of the algorithm, not vendor-specific implementation details.

Comment: Look here for loose index scan for mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-optimization.html ,extremely efficient.AFAIK as I know all dbs have this except Postgres.

Comment: @Mihai - SQL Server doesn't. Though if the index was on `franchise, worth` it is possible to simulate a skip scanning type behaviour with a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario 1: no index (read the whole table)

```
foreach(page in table.pages)
{
  foreach(row in page.rows)
  {
    Compare and accumulate franchise and worth from row
  }
}
-- Total IO = table.pages
```

Scenario 2: index on franchise only

```
foreach(page in index.pages)
{
  foreach(indexRow in page.rows)
  {
    tableRow = table.fetchRow(indexRow); // + 1 page of IO for each row
    Compare and accumulate franchise from indexRow and worth from tableRow
  }
}
-- Total IO = index.pages + table.rows
-- this is likely to be greater than Scenario 1...
--  so optimizer should prefer that plan instead.
```

Scenario 3: covering index (franchise, worth) in that order.

```
foreach(page in index.pages)
{
  foreach(row in page.rows)
  {
    Compare and accumulate franchise and worth from row
  }
}
-- Total IO = index.pages
-- Assuming that index is thinner than table, a win!
```

Scenario 4: different query with known list of franchises with index from Scenario 3

```
foreach(franchise in franchises)
{
  SELECT MAX(worth) FROM figurines WHERE franchise = franchise
}
```

...

```
foreach(franchise in franchises)
{
  search into the index looking for the last record with this franchise
  // this is usually less than 10 pages of IO in my experience.
}
-- Total IO = count of franchise * 10
-- super win!
```

Scenario 4 is different because it invoices a seek and not a scan.